# SQL - Return all records if column value matches pattern?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dataset

I have a query below that returns a very large set of data:

```
SELECT 
       a.id,
       a.name,
       c.c_name,
       l.t_id,
       t.n_id,
       l.lr_id, 
       l.created, 
       l.am_id, 
       e.e_name

FROM l 
INNER JOIN e 
        ON l.e_id=e.e_id
INNER JOIN t 
        ON l.t_id=t.t_id
INNER JOIN a 
        ON l.a_id=a.a_id
INNER JOIN c 
        ON a.p_c_id=c.c_id

WHERE lower(c.c_name) LIKE 'XXX' and l.date_created > 'YYYY-MM-DD'

ORDER BY a_name, created
```

The data is useful, but it's such a large dataset that it makes it very difficult to find the specific issues I'm searching for.

I'd like to be able to re-write the where clause to search for a string pattern in the e.e_name column. (WHERE e.e_name like XXXX) Then return ALL records for any a.id that has ANY e.e_name record that matches the search string.

I just can't figure out how to return all records for an a.id if it has an e.e_name match. :(

EDIT:   So the simplified data would look something like

```
555 | Bob Jones | Staff | 123 | 232 | 454 | 2015-02-27 1:00 | Location 1 
556 | Bob Jones | Staff | 123 | 232 | 456 | 2015-02-27 1:01 | Location 2
```

Essentially repeating for Bob Jones with many locations. So what I'm trying to do is find ALL the records for Bob Jones (or any other person) who has ANY record with a Location that matches a search string. My problem is that doing a LIKE or = search returns ONLY the records that match, and not all the surrounding records (which I need for context).

Comment: Not enough information here to offer any solid help. I assume that Exciter is your table aliased as "e". The query you posted doesn't have any aliases. I would think you could use a where exists predicate but hard to say for sure without seeing the table structures.

Comment: Also need to see sample data and desired results.

Comment: What is stopping you from where WHERE e.e_name like XXXX  ?

Comment: @Blam so the reason I can't use LIKE is because I just don't want the records that match the e_name pattern.  IF a single record matches the e.e_name pattern, I want to get ALL records for the a.id that had the e.e_name match.

This is because I don't care about the match, I care about the records before and after the match.

Comment: @TabAlleman so currently my results if I search for an e.e_name string match using LIKE or = returns only the records for an a.id that match.  What I'm trying to return is ALL records for ANY a.id that has  ANY e.e_name record that matches a search pattern.

The data results contain large amounts of private info so I can't share a result set here. :(

Comment: Can you post some dummy data and what the desired results would be for that dummy data?   Because right now I can't picture what you're describing, sorry.

Comment: @TabAlleman No problem!  So the simplified data would look something like

555 | Bob Jones | Staff | 123 | 232 | 454 | 2015-02-27 1:00 | Location 1
556 | Bob Jones | Staff | 123 | 232 | 456 | 2015-02-27 1:01 | Location 2

Essentially repeating for Bob Jones with many locations.  So what I'm trying to do is find ALL the records for Bob Jones (or any other person) who has ANY record with a Location that matches a search string.

My problem is that doing a LIKE or = search returns ONLY the records that match, and not all the surrounding records (which I need for context).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
SELECT 
       a.id,
       a.name,
       c.c_name,
       l.t_id,
       t.n_id,
       l.lr_id, 
       l.created, 
       l.am_id, 
       e.e_name
FROM l 
INNER JOIN e 
        ON l.e_id=e.e_id
INNER JOIN t 
        ON l.t_id=t.t_id
INNER JOIN a 
        ON l.a_id=a.a_id
INNER JOIN c 
        ON a.p_c_id=c.c_id
WHERE a.name IN (
  SELECT a1.name 
  FROM (All the same joins)
  WHERE e.e_name LIKE '%XXX%'
)
AND l.date_created > 'YYYY-MM-DD'
ORDER BY a_name, created
```

Comment: This appears to do exactly what I need! Wow, thank you!  Two quick questions just so I'm clear I understand it.:

1) Is t just that the nested select gets the filtered result set, and then the outer select filters for just those a.name's that meet the filtered criteria in the nested SELECT statement's WHERE clause?

2) If my understanding is correct, this means any other filter criteria should go in the same WHERE clause where you put e.e_name?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Your understanding is correct.   You are getting just the a.names that meet your criteria in the inner select, then the outer select gets all records associated with those names.

Answer (score 0):

I would, first of all, find all matches for your c.c_name and put them into temporary table, maybe add nonclustered index on it, then only query it

So that would be my approach:

```
SELECT c.c_id, c.c_name
INTO #TempC
FROM c
WHERE c.c_name LIKE 'XXXX'

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_id ON #Temp (c_id)

SELECT 
       a.id,
       a.name,
       c.c_name,
       l.t_id,
       t.n_id,
       l.lr_id, 
       l.created, 
       l.am_id, 
       e.e_name

FROM l 
INNER JOIN e 
        ON l.e_id=e.e_id
INNER JOIN t 
        ON l.t_id=t.t_id
INNER JOIN a 
        ON l.a_id=a.a_id
INNER JOIN #TempC AS C
        ON a.p_c_id=c.c_id

WHERE l.date_created > 'YYYY-MM-DD'

ORDER BY a_name, created
```

Maybe that would boost performance by a bit.

Also, is your query using indexes correct?